# Function Pointer present inside a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am working on a problem of running a function through a function pointer, which is a variable of a structure. I tried making a small code but I am not able to build it.
The error I am getting is as below:
[image] Please review the code below. The first statement in the main function is the cause of the error.
I am new to C.Thank you for your kind help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>

typedef int16_t (*reset_start_f)(void);        //typedef used for function Pointer

int ThermMgrSvc_Reset(void)
{
    int retVal;
    retVal=5;
    return retVal;
}



typedef struct
{

    reset_start_f reset;   // function pointer

}module_function_t;





static const module_function_t MODULE_TABLE[]=
{
    {(reset_start_f)ThermMgrSvc_Reset},
};


int main()
{
    int x2= MODULE_TABLE[0].(*reset)();           // This statement causing Error
    printf("x2= %d\n",x2);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***How*** is your code "failing"?

Comment: I am not able to build it.

Comment: Why? What errors do you get? Please [edit] your question to include the full and complete error output copy-pasted as text.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please review it. I am expecting that after the execution of the code, print statement should print 5.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour if `int16_t` is not a typedef for `int`.  The type of the function call expression must match the defined type of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is invalid:

```
int x2= MODULE_TABLE[0].(*reset)();
```

Because the structure access operator `.` must be followed immediately by the name of the field.  The dereferencing operator needs to be before the whole subexpression:

```
int x2= (*MODULE_TABLE[0].reset)();
```

Or, since function pointers are dereferenced implicitly when called, you can remove the `*` entirely:

```
int x2= MODULE_TABLE[0].reset();
```